# ANDROID - Add elements to screen dynamically during a loop

Tags: android, for-loop, tablelayout

everybody!

I'm making a Android program and I need to list some texts on TableLayout during a for loop. The problem is that I have a lot of lines and I wanna add them gradually, to not look like slow, but the Android only call the invalidate() method on the end of loop.

my source below:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
subcategoriasLayout.addView(tableLayout);  
for (Product product : listProdutos) {  
    TableRow itemRow = new TableRow(this);  
    TextView descricao = new TextView(this);  
    descricao.setText(produto.toString());  
    itemRow.addView(descricao);  

    itemRow.addView(new EditText(this), rowLayoutParams);  

    tableLayout.addView(itemRow);  

    if (++cont % 10 == 0) {  
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  

            public void run() {  
                subcategoriasLayout.invalidate();  
            }  
        }, 10);  
    }  
} 
subcategoriasLayout.invalidate();
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the loading of all these things in an AsyncProcess so that it looks like its fluid instead of using a loop.